# Why do webpages flicker when I scroll through them? (IE 8)

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer

This happened once before and it went away by itself, I think...or, I accidentally pushed some key that corrected it. Also, if it helps I have Sticky Keys on but I always have them on so I don't know why pages would flicker now.

Comment: What operating system are you running?

Comment: Win 7 64-bit...

Comment: Google around I say it seems a few people have a similar problem but the solution can be very specific so one specific forum may prove more useful. Is this a new PC?

Comment: Yes, an HP desktop but the problem has only risen one other time for a few minutes.

Comment: If it's a local shop then if it is now persistent you can to them to show them the problem reproduced and make it their problem

Comment: Does this only happen in Internet Explorer, or does it happen other places, too?

Answer (score -1):

What kind of flickering is it and what kind of pages does it happen with?

I find that the pages that exhibit this behavior the most are ones with plugins like Java or Flash. This is because they are not drawn by the browser, but by the plugin, so there is a bit of a disconnect between the plugin updating its part of the page and browser drawing the rest of the page during a scroll. It is not as bad with a faster system since it can handle the updating much quicker than a slower system, but even so, with the advanced and dynamic web-pages of today, pages put a much heavier load on the CPU (they "scale" with hardware advances), thus causing lag on anything but bleeding edge systems for some sites.

Comment: Just a slight flicker on even simple webpages with just text. It's more obvious on this blog page I was just reading: http://thoughtcatalog.com/2011/how-to-open-a-door/ when I scroll down using the arrow keys.

Comment: @verve All pages? Google search results? Does it only happen in the browser? What about scrolling a document in a text editor?

Comment: Well, in Word I don't see any flicker; just scrolled through a short document. And on this site it's barely noticeable.

Comment: On this site it looks like it's more of a wave than the blog. On the blog it looks like the text is "blinky" when I scroll through.

Comment: Do you have another browser available to test? What about other things like games? Do they display slowly? What happens if you drag a large window around the screen quickly?

Comment: In Firefox, the blog page is fine. I don't have games but my vidoes in VLC play fine.

Comment: What happens if you drag an Explorer or Firefox window around the screen quickly? Does it display fine or does it feel sluggish?

Comment: Windows move fine.

Comment: So it's not your drivers. Try running IE in safe-mode: `iexplore -extoff` to see if it still happens. If not, then one of your plugins or addons is the culprit.

Comment: How do I run it safe mode? What is "-extoff"? But I haven't installed any new plug-ins...

Comment: Instead of running IE from the shortcut, open the Run dialog (`Win+R`) and enter `iexplore -extoff`. You do not have Flash or Java installed? Either way, you can view any plugins or addons that are installed via `Tools->Manage addons`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Pages stopped flickering by itself.